# What is an "As-grown crystal"?

Tags: material-science, semiconductor-physics, crystals

I was going through a paper on a material. In that paper the authors mention ["as-grown crystal"](https://www.google.com/search?&as_epq=as+grown+crystal).

I tried looking for it on Wikipedia and searched it online but none of them tell what it is. So can anyone help?

Comment: I searched with google "as-grown crystal". and a number of references came up

Comment: That means they grew it, per the description, and did not do further processing (zone refining, annealing, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

Jon Custer's comment is correct.

As-grown means the crystals were grown according to a specific recipe, and then were not modified further. Examples of not as-grown would be if you annealed the crystals later in a second step or quenched them into ice water or other various processes.